# How to stream upload a file in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm setting a breakpoint inside the flatMap lambda and it takes ages to get there. Why and how to fix that? Currently, uploading a simple file of 19M which should take around 17s at 11Mbps takes around 70s. Does it read and pre-process the whole file first?

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<UploadResponse> upload(
            @RequestHeader("X-My-Meta-Info-Header") final UUID id,
            @RequestPart("file")
            @Parameter(content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE))
            final Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return filePartMono.flatMap(filePart -> fileStorageService.store(id, filePart)
                .doOnSuccess(f -> log.info("Uploading file took {}ms",
                    System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
                .map(f -> UploadResponse.builder()
                        .id(id)
                        .originalFileName(filePart.filename())
                        .build()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had the netty leak detection set to paranoid. Removing that solved my issue.